# Can't remove hidden characters from string

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I'm trying to remove hidden characters from a string that represents a date time. I'm using [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/073nJw) and you can see the line that tries to ParseExact fails.

Here is a snippet. Please refer to the fiddle link for working code.

```
var dateTime = "2015-04-14 07:30:00 PM"; //<= this throws an error from some hidden char
    dateTime = Regex.Replace(dateTime, @"[^\w:\s-]", ""); 
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
    DateTime dateWithTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
```

Comment: Can you enumerate over the string, and print the unicode number of the characters, so one can inspect what character is causing problems?

Comment: printing unicode characters https://dotnetfiddle.net/enZv4B

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: the `\s` is in a `[^]` group, so it ignores the `\s`,...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HH` in the format string refers to the 24-hour clock hours, which doesn't work when using AM/PM in the format string for PM times.

Change `HH` to `hh`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an invisible character.  Your use of `HH` conflicts with your use of `tt`.  `HH` is 24 hour time, but you are using `tt` to interpret PM (12 hour time).  Change it to `hh` and it works.

```
var dateTime = "2015-04-14 07:30:00 PM"; 
//dateTime = Regex.Replace(dateTime, @"[^\w:\s-]", ""); <= not needed
Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
DateTime dateWithTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine("OK");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change HH to hh.

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt
```